# How post data over https with urllib2?

Tags: django, https, urllib2, urllib

I want to integrate a credit card processing in my website using Paybox.com API's.

I have to send a POST request (using urllib2) to Paybox API's with credit card details (number, date, cvv) when a user submit a form.

How can I secure that? is it enougth to put https://www.mywebsite.com/card/processing in my form action?

How can I send POST data over HTTPS using urllib2?

PS: I work on Django.

Comment: There's a secret to this.  It's called "search".  The question has already been asked, and answered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python URLLib / URLLib2 POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238925/python-urllib-urllib2-post)

Answer (score 1):

Well in terms of security refer to this QA: [POST data encryption - Is HTTPS enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309997/post-data-encryption-is-https-enough)

As far as how to do it, here's an explanation about using urllib: http://www.codercaste.com/2009/11/28/how-to-use-the-urllib-python-library-to-fetch-url-data-and-more/

The idea is to use the urlencode command to create a parameters object for the request, then create a request object from the url and the parameters object, and then call urlopen on the request object in order to actually send the request.

Answer (score 0):

Here are solutions using *python-request* lib: http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/

- request using ssl: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification
- request using post: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests (should also allow *verify=True* parameter)

By the way, *python-request* is a very powerful and easy way to make requests.